# How to make a row of a matrix be the column of another matrix in an elegant way with Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

For example, let `B` be a `6 x 1` row matrix given by `[6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6]` and let `A` be a `4 x 6` matrix given by

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3], 
 [1, 0, 0, 0], 
 [2, 0, 0, 0], 
 [3, 0, 0, 0], 
 [4, 0, 0, 0], 
 [5, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Would it be any elegant way to make the elements of, say, the second column of `A` be the elements of `B`? That is, to make `A` be

```
[[0, 6, 2, 3], 
 [1, 6, 0, 0], 
 [2, 6, 0, 0], 
 [3, 6, 0, 0], 
 [4, 6, 0, 0], 
 [5, 6, 0, 0]]
```